# Raspberry Pi not showing pygame with screen as expected

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame

I am trying to get a **Raspberry Pi 3B+** to show live streams from 3 cameras, using a screen to get multiple instances of **omxplayer** to run on the positions I want them. This works exactly as expected.

The problem now is, that I want a static image in the last space on the screen. For that I wanted to use pygame, so I later could have more fun in that area, and maybe not only have an image.

The problem now is how the image is positioned:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVUOl.jpg (the image is the same size as the video feeds, and I had expected it to be in the bottom right of the monitor, with a thin black line towards the feed above and to the right of it)

I expected the white square to be directly under the top left video feed, but there are large black borders.

The Python code I use for showing the image is as follows:

```
import time
import pygame

transform_x = 958 #648 #how wide to scale the jpg when replaying
transfrom_y = 539 #how high to scale the jpg when replaying
offset_x = 0 #how far off to left corner to display photos
offset_y = 540 #how far off to left corner to display photos

try:
    pygame.init()

    info = pygame.display.Info() # You have to call this before pygame.display.set_mode()
    screen_width,screen_height = info.current_w,info.current_h
    window_width,window_height = screen_width,screen_height

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height))
    #screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0))
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False) #hide the mouse cursor  
    filename = "image.png"
    img=pygame.image.load(filename) 
    #img = pygame.transform.scale(img,(transform_x,transfrom_y))
    screen.blit(img,(offset_x,offset_y))
    pygame.display.flip() # update the display
    time.sleep(30) # pause
finally:
    pygame.quit()
```

I tried with `pygame.FULLSCREEN` and other modes, but none of them would go all the way to the edge of the monitor.

To show the picture I used this command:

```
sudo screen -dmS pic sh -c 'python pic.py'
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

So I got it fixed...

I had to comment out `disable_overscan=1` in `/boot/config.txt` ...

I didn't think of this, because omxplayer was at the positions I expected it to be..